# Vue sending param value, declaring which param to send as

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue function that I'm calling on page creation called `fetchReport`

That works fine, and I also have 2 other functions that I'm calling on change of select elements, which work as well, but here's my problem:

Currently, if I call handleTypeSelect or handleLocationSelect, they both submit the correct value but they submit it as itemType in the `fetchReport` call every time. I"m assuming it's because they only send one parameter value and that's the first parameter.

How can I modify this so that `handleTypeSelect` sends the value as `itemType` and `handleLocationSelect` sends the value as `locationID`?

```
created() {
    this.fetchReport();
},
methods: {
  fetchReport(itemType = '3', locationID = '10', startDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10), endDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10)) {
      axios.get('/report/assets/data', {params:{itemType: itemType, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, locationID: locationID}})
      .then(response => {
        // handle success
        console.log(response.data)
        this.rows = response.data
      })
  },
  handleTypeSelect() {
      this.fetchReport(itemTypes.value);
  },
  handleLocationSelect() {
      this.fetchReport(itemLocations.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor `fetchReport`'s arguments:

Instead of taking a series of arguments `(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, take a single parameter `(arg)`

This `arg` parameter will be an object including all the properties you need as arguments. As a followup, move the default values inside the function.

Result for you would be:

```
  fetchReport(myParams) {
      const defaults = { itemType: '3', locationID: '10', .... }; // list all other defaults, same as previous arguments
      const params = Object.assign(defaults, myParams);
      axios.get('/report/assets/data', { params })
      .then(response => {
        // handle success
        console.log(response.data)
        this.rows = response.data
      })
  },
```

Then, when you need to call fetchReport:

`fetchReport({ itemType: 'MyValue' })`

`fetchReport({ locationID: 'MyValue' })`

This is the best practice way of handling functions with multiple parameters when you don't want to think about order of parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use undefined to pass the first parameter.

```
 handleLocationSelect() {
      this.fetchReport(undefined, itemLocations.value);
  }
```

Comment: Won't that mess up the default value of '3' that I have for taskType, and instead send undefined?

Comment: @TomN. It won't . Default 3 will be used

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two params.

Use [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) to get the value `undefined`, because `window.undefined` can be [changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Description) in older browsers.

```
handleLocationSelect() {
    this.fetchReport(void, itemLocations.value);
}
```